# Importing a file to another file makes the value being unrecognized

Tags: python, function

I'm currently working on an online chatting system and to simplify my code, I'm using a function which is imported from 'main.py' to 'menu.py'.

```
def prompt():
    prompt=input(">")
```

Here's the problem : when I'm using it in 'menu.py', `prompt` is not recognized as a value since it originally comes from another file (in this case, 'main.py').
Is there a solution to make 'menu.py' recognize `prompt` ?

'menu.py' code

```
import main
in_menu=True ; in_signup=False ; in_login=False

while in_menu==True:
    print("sign.up") ; print("login")
    main.prompt() 
    if str(prompt)=="sign.up":
         in_menu=False ; in_signup=True ; in_login=False
    else:
        if str(prompt)=="login":
            in_menu=False ; in_signup=False ; in_login=True
        else:
            print(str(prompt), "is not a valid command")
```

I thank you in advance.

Comment: have the method `prompt()` do `return prompt`, and then when calling it assign the returned value to a variable: `prompt = main.prompt()`

Comment: i tried that, but unfortunately it didnt work. i might have not understood, do you mean putting `return prompt`after `prompt=input(">")`in main.py and putting `prompt=main.prompt()` in menu.py after `main.prompt()`or am i dumb lol